# Nginx read secret and webhook headers

Tags: nginx, networking

A Webhook from Github is passing through Nginx proxy.

The webhook uses secret and the header is sent as X-Hub-Signature-256.

I want to make Nginx filtering requests, i.e I need Nginx to take the webhook header value and compare it to $SECRET_TOKEN. If the secret is right, it will send 200 and If not, 403.

I thought of something like this, but could find a way to implement it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  location /payload {
      
      #Read the header sent by the webhook
      #If the header content matches $SECRET_TOKEN I defined on Nginx then return 200
      #Else, return 403 
  }
}
```

Please help with implementing this pseudo as I couldn't find any example online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On `http` level, create a `map`:

```
map $http_x_hub_signature_256 $retcode {
    <token> 200;
    default 403;
}
```

And your location would be:

```
location /payload {
    return $retcode;
}
```

Comment: I created a map as you offered, inside http { }. Then inside server { } I put location { } as you offered. Now I get 403 on every get request. No matter if the $SECRET_TOKEN is given on not. What usage do we have with variable $http_x_hub_signature_256 you offered?

Comment: HTTP headers are referenced using `$http_` prefix, with all letters converted to lower case and dashes replaced with underscores. So, it is the header you are sending. You need to enter the actual token in the map, you cannot use variables.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. So I cannot call env var from inside nginx.conf. I will enter the actual token. But then there's another issue: The map takes the actual value of http_x_hub_signature_256. So instead of decrypting it, the value is "sha256=....". In that way, comparing it to the actual token value, will always be false and return 403. Is there a way to decrypt sha256 from nginx.conf? After the decryption I will get the actual token which will be compared to the actual token I gave, and then will receive 200.

Comment: This cannot be done in nginx, you need to implement this in your application.

Comment: Are you sure? Then whats the point of using Nginx as proxy..?

Comment: The point is to serve static files efficiently and terminate TLS and do load balancing with multiple backends.

Comment: You can take a look into https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html how to perform complex authentication requests in nginx.